# How can I have server Admin level config of a Teamcity plugin available the agent side?

Tags: teamcity

I am developing a Teamcity plugin with standard server and agent side.
On the server side I have a Admin page where the user input some parameters and I save them with

```
CustomSettingsManager.getCustomSettings(pluginDescriptor).setValue(ATT,value)
```

My question is how I can get those saved values on the plugin side?

I am using an `AgentLifeCycleAdapter` so I have objects like `AgentRunningBuild` and `BuildRunnerContext` but I cannot find nothing to fetch plugin saved params.

Answer (score 1):

The solution i found is to create a `AbstractBuildParametersProvider` that collects information from `CustomSettingsManager` and add provide as a parameter to the build.

```
public class SettingsParameterProvider extends AbstractBuildParametersProvider {

private final CustomSettingsManager customSettingsManager;

private final PluginDescriptor pluginDescriptor;

public SettingsParameterProvider(@NotNull CustomSettingsManager settingsManager,
        @NotNull PluginDescriptor descriptor) {
    this.customSettingsManager = settingsManager;
    this.pluginDescriptor = descriptor;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParameters(SBuild build, boolean emulationMode) {
    return ServerSettingsManager
            .loadAsMap(customSettingsManager.getCustomSettings(pluginDescriptor));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me before was to call `((AgentRunningBuild) build).getBuildFeaturesOfType(MY_PLUGIN)`. This returns a collection of `AgentBuildFeature` objects, and you can call `feature.getParameters()` on each.

Example [here](https://github.com/sferencik/ClutterStats/blob/master/clutter-stats-agent/src/main/java/sferencik/teamcity/clutterstats/BuildStatusListener.java).

Comment: but, IIUC, that is using Build Features, which are at build configuration level, not whole server configuration settings, right?

Comment: Oh, yes. What kind of properties does your plugin set? What's a "whole server configuration setting"?